input broken when script called from another script
ENV:  Oracle Linux 9, Python 3.9
I have a script which 1) installs dependencies for the second script from a given collection of WHL files, and 2) launches the "action" script once the dependencies are installed.  That all seems to be working well.
def spawn_config_script_and_die(program, exit_code=0):
    subprocess.Popen(program)
    sys.exit(exit_code)
spawn_config_sript_and_die(['python3', 'confi_script.py', '-H', host_name, '-l', log_level, '-p', config_path])

The issue that I am having is that "input" commands do not wait for user input when the second script is launched from the first.  The script just proceeds as if the user pressed "Enter" without providing a legitimate response.  If I run the second script directly, "input" commands work fine.  I'm sure this is some simple/known issue, but I'm just not finding/seeing it.
I tried to exit the first script once the second script was launched, but that didn't make any difference.

How, exactly, are you launching the second script?  Without a [mcve], we can only guess at the reasons for the problem.

Edited the topic to include how I am calling the second script.

subprocess.Popen "captures" the stdin of the launched command, allowing your script to feed lines into it.  If you want to have the process inherit your stdin, you can try passing stdin=sys.stdin.

passing stdin=sys.stdin did not work for subprocess.Popen(), but I changed it to subprocess.run(), and that allowed me to pass stdin=sys.stdin.  Testing proved that it is operational.  Thank you!

Don't put SOLVED in the title. You indicate that a question is solved by accepting one of the answers.

As Tim Roberts mentioned in the comments, stdin=sys.stdin needed to be passed to the script being called.  However, I was unable to do so with subprocess.Popen().  I had to use subprocess.run() in order to successfully pass stdin=sys.stdin.

It should work with Popen() as well. The answers in the duplicate question use Popen().
